# ucwords value in an array

Tags: php, arrays

In my $_POST, I am wondering how can I apply ucwords on the value "english" and "math" inside the array.

```
Array
    (
        [name1] => Array
            (
                [0] => english
                [1] => 2
            )

        [name2] => Array
            (
                [0] => math
                [1] => 1
            )

        [submit] => Add to List
    )
```

I am still confused in manipulating an array, so I tried this, but no luck.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
  if(is_array($value))
    {
      foreach($value as $key2 => $value2)
      {
        $value2 = ucwords($value2);
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By changing those values (as with any other variable). As it's an array, this is fundamentally like this (for `"english"` in your example):

```
$_POST['name1'][0] = ucwords($_POST['name1'][0]);
```

You are using a `foreach` loop to iterate over each of those values, that's basically like the following (again simplified) example (which does not work in your case, just to make this more visible):

```
$value2 = $_POST['name1'][0];
$value2 = ucwords($value2);
```

As this example shows, you're changing the value of `$value2` but not the according entry in `$_POST`. You can use a reference or aliasing in PHP to achieve this:

```
$value2 = &$_POST['name1'][0];
$value2 = ucwords($value2);
```

This will change  `$_POST['name1'][0]` as well, because it has been [aliased <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) as `$value2` and now is a reference to it.

[`foreach`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/foreach) does support references as well:

```
foreach($_POST['name1'] as &$value2)
{
    $value2 = ucwords($value2);
}
unset($value2); # remove the alias for safety reasons.
```

See the `&` sign inside the `foreach` header in front of `$value2`. This makes `$value2` an alias to each array entry while iterating over the array.

As you are iterating over two arrays inside each other, you need to apply this twice, here is the full example:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => &$value)
{
    if (is_array($value))
    {
        foreach ($value as $key2 => &$value2)
        {
            $value2 = ucwords($value2);
        }
        unset($value2); # remove alias for safety reasons.
    }
}
unset($value); # remove alias for safety reasons.
```

Naturally it's possible to prevent aliasing here and access those values directly by using the keys:

```
foreach ($_POST as $keyOuter => $valueOuter)
{
    if (is_array($valueOuter))
    {
        foreach ($valueOuter as $keyInner => $valueInner)
        {
            $_POST[$keyOuter][$keyInner] = ucwords($valueInner);
        }
    }
}
```

Which is probably better readable and easier to understand how it works because it does not uses any aliasing/references.

Answer (score 3):

using reference `&`

```
foreach($value as $key2 => &$value2)
      {
        $value2 = ucwords($value2);
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can do this in a similar way to your posted code if you pass the array by reference instead (using the ampersand & operator), so your original `foreach` line could be:

```
foreach ($value as $key2 => &$value2) { // note use of & here

    $value2 = ucwords($value2);
}
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Edit: Whoops, Haim has it written correctly - you would pass the `$value` by reference for the `foreach` loop you're assigning the new value within. I have amended the code above.

Answer (score 2):

Your `foreach` is almost right, so just...

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    if(is_array($value))
    {
        $_POST[$key][0] = ucwords($_POST[$key][0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: if the math,english is in second key, how can that be working?

Comment: Well, we supposing the array layout will always be that.

Comment: :-s (i too lazy to debate with you)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
  if(is_array($value))
   {
      array_map('ucwords',$value);
   }
}
```

Comment: "try this" (code-only) answers are low-value on StackOverflow because they do a poor job of educating the OP and thousands of future researchers.  Please always include some explanation of how your code works and why it is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

This is already built into php

```
$array = array('foo', 'bar','yup');
$lower = array_map('strtolower', $array);
$upper = array_map('strtoupper', $array);
$ucwords = array_map('ucwords', $array);
$ucfirst = array_map('ucfirst', $array);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low-value on StackOverflow because they do a poor job of educating the OP and thousands of future researchers.  Please always include some explanation of how your code works and why it is a good idea.  Please directly answer the question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_POST[$key][$key2] = ucwords($value2);
```

Comment: too lazy (15 chars, please revised your answer anyway)

Comment: Code-only answers are low-value on StackOverflow because they do a poor job of educating the OP and thousands of future researchers.  Please always include some explanation of how your code works and why it is a good idea.